# Not being able to use promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use promises in node.

But, the then part is not being executed.
The first function returns a resolve() instance.
How can I fix this?

This is the code:

```
exports.refresh_access_token = function (environment_hash) {

    ...

    Model.update(values, {where: where}).then(function () {
        console.log('updated!');
        resolve("Success!");

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error on update');
    });

    ...

}

async.map(accounts, function (account) {
    module.exports.refresh_access_token(account.environment_hash).then(function () {
        console.log('async called back');
    });
}
```

Comment: `The first function returns a resolve() instance` what is a resolve instance?

Comment: it's just the resolve('sucess'); line

Comment: but what is `resolve`? it has no special built in meaning, and isn't defined in your code

Comment: I'm just following this: https://davidwalsh.name/promises
it uses resolve('Success!'); in one of the examples

Comment: Resolve in that example is the callback that tells the promise to, well, resolve. It is not a global variable. Your example will be throwing an exception.

Comment: How can I return a success so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but there are several errors you can fix:

1. To let the caller know when an internal promise is done, you must return that promise.  So, add `return` to `return`Model.update(...)`
2. `resolve()` is not a globally available function so there's no point in trying to call it from within a `.then()` handler.  In fact, that probably causes an exception to be thrown because `resolve` is not defined.
3. When you are inside a `.then()` handler, the original promise is already resolved.  You don't need to resolve anything.  To return a value as the resolved value of the parent promise, just return that value.
4. When you log from within a `.catch()` handler, if you want the host promise to stay rejected, you have to re-throw the error.  Otherwise, the error becomes "handled" and the promise changes to resolved.
5. Then, in your second code block, it really does not make sense to mix the `async` library with promises.  They are different approaches to managing asynchronous operations.  Pick one scheme or the other - don't mix.  If you already have a promise like you do, then you can just return that promise and let the caller use the promise.  No need for the `async` library when you already have promises.

You can fix those like this:

```
exports.refresh_access_token = function (environment_hash) {

    ...

    return Model.update(values, {where: where}).then(function () {
        console.log('updated!');
        return "Success!";

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error on update');
        // after logging, make sure promise stays rejected
        throw err;
    });

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still not working. I want to run a certain process for every element of my database in parellel (the refresh_access_token function) and then execute another process only when the refresh_access_token has finished

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano - There's zero way we can help you with the larger problem when all  you include is this much code and when you don't detail exactly where things go wrong (e.g. explain what debugging and troubleshooting you've already done).  You've just described a whole bunch of stuff that has absolutely nothing to do with the code in your question.  We're doing the best we can with the code you've shown and the description you've provided.  Heck, I've already given you four things to fix in just that much code.  Nothing else we can here with what we have to go on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I would like to help you solve my issue. But I know too little about Promises to do this. I just know that the code is not working as I expected. I'm going to study more about it and check if I'm on the right path. I'm accepting your answer as a signal of gratitude for your help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, will remove the noise :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your promise to be able to use `then`

`return Model.update(...)`

Comment: I added the return Model, but still nothing happens.

Comment: every time you use a promise you need to return it so the calling function can wait for it, for the code you shown it should work, maybe there is a problem in the code you don't show

Comment: I edited the code. I'm calling the function inside a async.map function.  Because I want to run a certain process for every element of my database in parellel (the refresh_access_token function) and then execute another process only when the refresh_access_token has finished @user3